# ¿Qué archivos de un proyecto de Delphi XE7 debo subir al Github para que otro pueda abrirlo sin problemas?

Tags: github, delphi

Soy bastante novato en el mundo de la programación y comencé con *Delphi XE7* hace un par de meses, resulta que ahora quiero subir mi proyecto a *Github* para que pueda verlo un amigo y a su vez editarlo y tal.

¿Qué tengo que subir específicamente a *Github* para que el pueda abrirlo y compilarlo sin problemas?

Creo que debo subir los archivos .dproj, .pas, .dfm, .fmx. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

> **PD:** El proyecto es un Multidevice Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los tips ficheros estandard para los proyectos delphi son los siguientes:

- .**pas** Ficheros de código fuente; Units o formularios
- .**dcu** Fichero compilado (equivalente al .pas)
- .**dfm** Formulario de Delphi VCL (parte visual)
- .**fmx** Formulario de Delphi multiplataforma FMX (parte visual)
- .**dpr** Fichero de proyecto de aplicación
- .**dproj** Fichero de proyecto para versiones nuevas
- .**res** Fichero de recursos
- .**dpk** Fichero de proyecto (para packages); Equialente a un .dpr
- .**dcp** Fichero de package compilado de diseño (equivalente a un .dpk)
- .**bpl** Fichero de package compilado de runtime (equivalente a un .dpk)
- .**bpg**/.**groupproj**/.**bdsproj** Fichero de grupo de proyectos
- .**dcr** Fichero de recursos compilado (equivalente a .res)
- .**xml** Fichero de manifiesto del proyecto
- .**deployproj** Información de Delployment (multiplataforma)
- .**dof** Opciones del proyecto
- .**dsk** Ficheros con opciones del IDE referentes al proyecto
- .**dro** Información referente a objetos del repositorio
- .**local** Opciones locales del proyecto (versiones nuevas)
- .**identcache** Opciones de caché del IDE referentes al proyecto (verisones nuevas)
- .**ico**/.**icns** Icono/s de la aplicación

Estos son los que se me ocurren ahora, tal vez me dejo alguno.
Deberías subir todos los ficheros que NO SON COMPILADOS y puedes omitir los  que son opciones temporales.
Segun la lista que hay arriba deberías subir los siguientes:

***pas dfm fmx dpr dproj res dpk bpg groupproj bdsproj dcr xml deployproj ico icns***

**Actualización**: Además de estos que son los relacionados con Delphi, si en tu proyecto has usado otros ficheros externos (como ficheros de imagen que cargas de disco, ficheros de Base de Datos locales,...) también deberás añadirlos.